# Finding a transition matrix exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential

We are given a matrix $A =  \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -3 & -9\\
0 & 5 & 18\\
0 & -2 & -7
\end{bmatrix}$ and we have to find a transition matrix for it.

I have computed a characteristic polynomial $(\lambda + 1)^3$, so the eigevnalue with algebraic multtiplicity 3 is $\lambda = -1$

Then, computing $A - \lambda \mathbb{I} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -3 & -9\\
0 & 6 & 18 \\
0 & -2 & -6
\end{bmatrix}$ and $(A - \lambda \mathbb{I})^2 = 0$

For constructing a transition matrix we have to find $ v \in Ker(A - \lambda \mathbb{I})^2$, $ v \notin Ker(A - \lambda \mathbb{I})$. This is true for example for $v = (0,0,1)$, and then computing $(A - \lambda \mathbb{I}) v = (-9, 18, -6)$, which are the columns for the transition matrix.

I don't know how to find the third column for it though, since $(A - \lambda \mathbb{I})^2 v = (0,0,0)$, which is not the right solution. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Since I’m having trouble with this problem I’m not sure i understand them right. I think that in this case, $v$ and $(A - \lambda I)v$ are definitely the generalized eigenvectors which form two of the columns of the transition matrix, but I’m not sure about the third one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When finding a transition matrix you first find out for what exponent $(A-\lambda I)^k=0$ which is $k=2$ here. And $k=2$ is the lowest possible exponent because $(A-\lambda I) \ne 0$.

First you now want to find a complement $U$ of $\ker(A-\lambda I)$ in $\ker((A-\lambda I)^2) = \mathbb R^3$ which you did (it has the basis $v=(0,0,1)$, i.e. $U= \text{span}(v)$).

Then we go "one level down" and find a complement of $(A-\lambda I)(U)$ in $\ker(A-\lambda I)$, that is: a vector $w$ in $\ker(A-\lambda I)$ that is not element of $(A-\lambda I)(U) = \text{span}(-9, 18, -6)$. What that means in this case is: we want to find a second eigenvector of $A$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$. We see that $w=(0,3,-1)$ satisfies $(A-\lambda I)w=0$ but $w$ does not lie in $\text{span}(-9, 18, -6)$.

We now have three vectors consisting of a basis that can be used as the columns of a transition matrix: Set
$$S= \begin{pmatrix}-9&0&0\\18&0&3\\-6&1&-1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Then $$S^{-1}AS=J=\begin{pmatrix}-1&1&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&-1 \end{pmatrix}$$
which is the Jordan normal form of $A$.

In terms of the change of basis the matrix $S$ represents the identity operator with respect to the bases $B= ((-9, 18, -6), (0,0,1), (0,3,-1))$ and $C=((1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1))$. The base $B$ was chosen so that the matrix $J$ has the given form: we put the two "corresponding" vectors $(A-\lambda I)(0,0,1)$ and $(0,0,1)$ in the first two columns to form the block of size two and the last eigenvector $(0,3,-1)$ in the third column to form the block of size one.

Comment: Could I for example divide $(-9, 18, -6)$ by 3 or would this make a difference?
One more question and sorry if it is off topic, if we have different eigenvalues, is it necessary for the generalized eigenvectors corresponding to them to be linearly independent? For example when you stated: a vector $w$ in $ker(A−\lambda I)$ that is not element of $span(−9,18,−6)$, would the same apply if these two vectors were corresponded to different eigenvalues?

Comment: If you have more than one eigenvalue you look at each one of those seperately in the way I described (looking for the lowest exponent $k$ with $(A-\lambda I)^k=0$ and so on...). Then you just write all the acquired generalised eigenvectors into one big transition matrix - first a few columns corresponding to the first eigenvalue $\lambda_1$, then the columns corresponding to $\lambda_2$ and so on.
Dividing $(-9, 18, -6)$by $3$ would make a difference in that case because you would lose the structural aspect that $(-9, 18, -6) = (A-\lambda I)(0,0,1)$ so the entry $1$ in $J$ will become a $3$.